# How to auto save conversation in MS office communicator 2007 R2 like in Lync?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, lync, office-communicator-2007

I am using MS office communicator 2007 R2. Every time when i do chatting from this tool all previous communication history not gets available. I have used Lync previously which auto store all the previous communication in communication history folder in outlook. So is there any setting by which i can get the behavior like Lync in this tool to see previous chats logs.

Comment: The [default setting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Frequently-Asked-Questions-122809ff-d320-4ca4-918c-6e4527ff561c) is to archive these messages if its been disabled its likely done by your IT staff.

Comment: @Ramhound I have already done the below step but still outlook it is not showing any 'Outlook conversation history folder': "On the Personal tab, select the Save my instant message conversations in the Outlook Conversation History folder option, and then click OK."

Answer (score -2):

This Security Update should work.

[Direct link to download for:Security Update for Microsoft Communicator 2007 R2 (KB2708980)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30117)

Save and read install detail for this patch.

Comment: I see no evidence that this patch would solve the author's problem.  I read what was fixed, no reference, to any of the keywords I used.  Provide more information on the reason this patch would solve the author's problem, quote it, if you have to please.

Comment: Three privately reported vulnerabilities in Microsoft Lync. The most severe vulnerabilities could allow remote code execution if a user views shared content that contains specially crafted TrueType fonts. Quoted from Microsoft Destription